# JavaFX8: How do I set the initially focused control in a Stage?

Tags: dialog, javafx, javafx-8

I am using `Stage` to create a simple dialog that contains a `Label`,  a `TextField` and two `Button`s, namely *OK* and *Cancel*.

When my application runs on Java7, the one and only `TextField` control has keyboard focus implicitly.  This is not the case on Java8.  On Java8, the user must click the `TextField` with the mouse to begin typing into it.

It seems as if I will have to extend `Stage` and override `Stage.showAndWait()` to request focus for my `TextField` control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Invoke [`Node.requestFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--) in one of the following ways:

- Use [`Stage.setOnShown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnShown-javafx.event.EventHandler-). The `EventHandler` you pass on in this method will get called as soon as the Stage is displayed.
- Use [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) for requesting the initial focus.

Here's an example (JavaFX 11):

```java
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public final class CustomDialog extends Dialog<String> {
  private final TextField mField = new TextField();

  private CustomDialog( final Window owner ) {
    super( owner, "My Dialog" );

    final var contentPane = new StackPane();
    contentPane.getChildren().add( mField );
    
    final var dialogPane = getDialogPane();
    dialogPane.setCOntent( contentPane );

    Platform.runLater( () -> mField.requestFocus() );
  }
}
```